# Cannot access to WSL2 port opened via IPv6 from Windows host

Tags: node.js, linux, port, wsl-2

I have a node-server running at WSL2 Ubuntu-20.04.

`netstat -tulpn` in WSL shows the following ports:
[image]

The ports specified as `0.0.0.0:8080` can be accessed in both WSL and Windows via `127.0.0.1:8080` url

My issue is that the ports specified as `:::3006` can be accessed via `127.0.0.1:3006` only inside WSL, but from Windows, it works only via the network URL like `http://172.28.100.200:3006`.

When I send the request to `127.0.0.1:3006` from Windows, there is no connection error, but the server inside WSL does not receive it while using the network address, it does.

How can I investigate this and make the Windows port at `127.0.0.1:3006` forward requests into the same port in WSL?

**UPDATE:**

So I solved this by adding a port proxy, but again, WSL network IP is needed for this to work:
[image]

Any chance to avoid using network IP?